# How to use Keycloak with PKCE

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect, pkce

I'm trying to get token from keycloak using pkce with authorization_code flow without success.

Request parameters (from postman):

```
curl -X POST \
  http://keycloak-ar.uat.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWJyYWFvLxF1ZWlyb3o6MTIz' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 172' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: keycloak-ar.uat.com' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=spring-boot-app&username=apiuser&client_secret=cd78e82a-e86a-4bf3-a3d7-7c01cec49396&code=qjrzSW9gMiUgpUvqgEPE4_-8swvyCtfOVvg55o5S_es'
```

Keycloak log:

```
22:50:01,962 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-146) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=myrealm, clientId=spring-boot-app, userId=null, ipAddress=10.128.2.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cannot comment, so adding as an answer.

```
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=spring-boot-app&username=apiuser&client_secret=cd78e82a-e86a-4bf3-a3d7-7c01cec49396&code=qjrzSW9gMiUgpUvqgEPE4_-8swvyCtfOVvg55o5S_es'
```

A couple of things: 
1) `client_secret` is optional 
2) `redirect_uri` is missing. It is **REQUIRED**, and must be exactly as the one used while making request for `authorization code`.

About `username`, it is definitely not needed, but cannot say if it's presence will cause issues. Better to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example with java/spring-boot using this flow?

Comment: Yes, have a look at [this](https://github.com/git-adarsh/config-idp-keycloak/tree/master/java/com/auth/ms/services). It has the discussed flow.